# Error with Eigen vector logarithm invalid use of incomplete type

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

I am trying to compute the element-wise natural logarithm of a vector using the Eigen library, here's my code:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

void function(VectorXd p, VectorXd q) {
    VectorXd kld = p.cwiseQuotient(q);
    kld = kld.log();
    std::cout << kld << std::endl;
}
```

However when compiling with

`g++ -I eigen_lib  -std=c++11 -march=native test_eigen.cpp -o test_eigen`

I get

`test_eigen.cpp:15:23: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘const class Eigen::MatrixLogarithmReturnValue<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >’ kld = kld.log();`

What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VectorXd::log()` is `MatrixBase<...>::log()` which computes the matrix logarithm of a square matrix. If you want the element-wise logarithm you need to use the array functionality:

```
kld = kld.array().log();
// or:
kld = log(kld.array());
```

If all your operations are element-wise, consider using `ArrayXd` instead of `VectorXd`:

```
void function(const Eigen::ArrayXd& p, const Eigen::ArrayXd& q) {
    Eigen::ArrayXd kld = log(p/q);
    std::cout << kld << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in this case, since I'm only operating on vectors, ArrayXd are a very nice idea

Answer (score 4):

To do element-wise operations on Eigen objects (`Matrix` or `Vector`), you need to specify that. This is done by by adding `.array()` to the `Matrix`/`Vector` object like so:

```
kld = kld.array().log();
```

See this [tutorial](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html).

P.S. `MatrixLogarithmReturnValue` is part of the [unsupported modules](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__MatrixFunctions__Module.html) for matrix functions.